# Karabiner-Elements: How to disable a group of keys in a simple way?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

Is there a simple way to disable a group of keys in complex modifications in Karabiner-Elements?

Consider an example:

Under the following condition

```
  "set_variable": {
      "name": "con-1",
      "value": 1
  }
```

I want to disable all alphabets/numbers/simbols (or most of them at least), except for `a` and `b`.

Just for reference, [this page](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/145) discusses how to disable individual keys. Applying this approach to many many keys is not efficient.

I appreciate your insight in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT: I just added two "[ ]" brackets to the final "to":[{ -part, as their lack got s.o.an [error] !***

==========================================================================

So, here is a "final version" (some notes to/from a first attempt are appended at bottom):

... some sample code that excludes any typing except letters "a" & "b".
This example is set to only work in TextEdit (for testing purposes) but of course you can change/delete this "conditions" (in last manipulator).

– The "Excluding" is prepared by `Shft-Ctrl-A` which solely sets `"none_but_ab"` to true (1).
– Next in line is a Stop-manipulator (security first); it sets `"none_but_ab"` to "0" after holding "x" 2 sec.
– Both following parts out-put our "a" and "b" letters, ***excluding*** them from following ***annihilation***.
– The fatal last manipulator grabs "any: key_code" and renders it to "none" …
– Be careful with your Stop-mechanism: singular keys work best, modified combos may fail!

– Some more ideas:
By adding "command" ("shift") to the last "from", you could prevent app-Cmd-shortcuts (capital letters).
Karabiner El. can start before login (Preferences > 'Copy the current …'); "password" would be affected!
I also would like to know how "Shift" could be applied to "any":"key_code", forcing capital letters, or if numbers can somehow be "selected". Well, let's see …

```
{ "description": "=============  vk_none but a,b  ============= ",
   "manipulators": [
        {
           "from": { "key_code": "a",
                     "modifiers": {
                         "mandatory": ["left_shift", "left_control"]
                   }              },
             "to": [
                    { "set_variable": {
                      "name": "none_but_ab",
                      "value": 1 }    }
                   ],
           "type": "basic"
         },
         {
           "from": { "key_code": "x" },
     "parameters": { "basic.to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds": 2000 },
"to_if_held_down": [
                    { "key_code": "x" },
                    { "set_variable": {
                      "name": "none_but_ab",
                      "value": 0 }    }
                   ],
           "type": "basic"
         },
         { "from": { "key_code": "a" },
             "to": [ { "key_code": "a" } ],
           "type": "basic" }, 
         { "from": { "key_code": "b" },
             "to": [ { "key_code": "b" } ],
           "type": "basic" },
         { 
     "conditions": [
                    { "name": "none_but_ab",
                      "type": "variable_if",
                      "value": 1 },
                    { "bundle_identifiers": [
                              "^com.apple.TextEdit" ],
                      "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                    }
                   ],
           "from": { "any": "key_code",
                     "modifiers": {
                          "optional": ["any"] }
                   },
             "to": [ { "key_code": "vk_none" } ],
           "type": "basic"
                   }
                   ]
}
```

(Here are some remains from a first (deleted) answer at this:

`note the twisted "any: key_code" part that calls every key, including "modifiers…any"`

`Interestingly 'from-to' units within`<strike>{manipulators: …}</strike> **Karabiner.json** `are worked through from top to bottom` ***until one is executable***.
`So if you want particular letters (a, b) to work nonetheless, you must call them previously.`

`Starting value for any variable is "0"` … values will "live" while Karabiner is running!

`… while experimenting I made my monitor sleep, but when I typed my pw – one letter simply was not recognised. I had to start from an external drive and change my code.` )

Comment: [I add former comments (to the deleted 2nd "answer"): ] ________________________________ Most importantly - thanks for the great answers. – bmike♦ _______________________________
Oh, you're welcome – and probably right. I'll later on look into what information from my 1st try is worth appending to the newer one; just was so concentrated, I didn't do it right away. Thanks for your reputation points! – clemsam lang

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I am trying to create a simple version of vi mode. I want to nullify keys other than those used in Normal Mode, like 'jkhlwbgG0$oOiI'. But your code gives an error '[error] [grabber] complex_modifications json error: `to` should be array: {"conditions":[{"name":"none_but_ab","type":"variable_if","value":1},{"bundle_identifiers":["^com.apple.TextEdit"],"type":"frontmost_application_if"}],"from":{"any":"key_code","modifiers":{"optional":["any"]}},"to":{"key_code":"vk_none"},"type":"basic"}
'. Am I missing something?

Comment: I at first was not quite sure that I understood your question (I had pasted my posted code into karabiner.json and it worked). It seems "[error] …" just expects "[ ]" brackets. These are only needed in "from" when there is more than one {} in your "from": [ {…}, {…}, {…} ] but "to" wants them EVERY time – funny that my code worked nonetheless … but I DID change this above !!!

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful code! I used it in my simple Vim mode for KE. You can find it in a file `Nullify_keys.json` in [here](https://github.com/spring-haru/my_KE) if you are interested.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if what I think is true: I looked into your GitHub code – do you really have to repeatedly call some doublet keys like "b" and "e" ? … If they are "recognised" in your 1st "from…to" the second one won't even be called. I suspect, you might omit these (2nd) doublets. Nice work, your "Vim modes" !